# Call another function after timeout is reached

Tags: typescript

I have the following code in JavaScript which I'd like to convert to TypeScript:

```
testJS(): void {
 $timeout(function () {
  this.done = true;
 }, 1).then(function () {
  $timeout(function () {
   this.done = false;                        
  }, 1000);
});              
}
```

I am trying to use the setTimeout function in TypeScript but I am not quite sure how to solve the ".then" part. Can anyone help me on this? The code so far:

```
testTS(): void {
 setTimeout(function () {
  this.done = true;
 }, 1).then(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
   this.done = false;                        
  }, 1000);
});              
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1: Make a promise using `setTimeout`

```
function wait(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

## Step 2: Use the promises

```
function testJS(): void {
    wait(1).then(() => {
        this.done = true;
        return wait(1000)
    }).then(() => {
        this.done = false;   
    })
}
```

## Step 2 (alternative): `await` the promises

```
async function testJS2(): Promise<void> {
    await wait(1)
    this.done = true;
    await wait(1000)
    this.done = false;   
}
```

Notice: The `this` binding in unclear in your example.

Comment: Thank you. Will try it out.